# How to tell Google a post was deleted and copied?

Tags: blogger

I had a blogger post and due to some difficulties (a glitch of some sort) I had to delete it and recopy it as a new post. I noticed the post was already ranking in Google. Will Google see this as duplicate content or will it fix itself?

Comment: No, it will see it as new Content. But could add an canonical tag and a redirect to the new link, it will know.

Comment: Isn't it a different link?

Comment: Also, look into requesting that Google re-crawl your link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a custom redirect (in Blogger Settings › Search preferences) 
from the old post URL to the new post URL ?